# Fechas en Report Viewer

Tags: date, reportviewer

Tengo un reporte en `RV`, el cual incluye fechas.

Las formateo de la siguiente manera:

```
Format(<fecha>,"dd-MMM-yy")
```

la fecha aparece como `21-Apr-19,`
sin embargo, necesito la fecha así:  `21-abr-19 (mes en español)`

Y en los formularios las fechas aparecen en español.
¿Qué hará falta?

Answer (score 0):

Necesita cambiar el formato de la siguiente manera:

```
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy",new Locale("es", "ES"))).format($F{FECHA}))
```